# How can i use texture image as background

Tags: css

I have used a texture as background of a div.But its not working accurately.The background is like the following image. How can I fix the problem??

The css code that i have used is

`.promotion {
    background:url(img/promotion_image.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
 }`

Comment: Please attach an image.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.promotion {
  background: url(img/promotion_image.png) repeat top left;
}
```

and it should work with just one line of code.

Mind that width and height are necessary for the div to be displayed.

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r3uLf3w1/

Answer (score 0):

You’re setting the `background` property, which is a shorthand of all the `background-...` properties, possibly overwriting the properties defined later. Please try the following code:

```
.promotion {
  background-image: url(img/promotion_image.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Note the `background` property is now set to `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
   .promotion {
      background: url("image path") repeat 0 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a width and height to the class of the div. Did you do this ?